# Using !important in CSS for every style element

Tags: css, styling

I have the following problem, i need the "ul[editable] li" class to be dominant over "#menu li". I know I can use !important as follows:

```
#menu li {
    border:solid 1px #9f693a;
    outline:solid 1px #89552a;
    background:url(images/bg.png);
}

ul[editable] li {
    background-color: #333333 !important; 
    border-color: #0d0d0d !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

I want to say something like this:

```
ul[editable] li !important {
    ....
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you cannot use the !important statement in the selector. The only thing you can do is make the second selector more specific, (Or the first one less specific of course).

For example:

```
#menu li {
    border:solid 1px #9f693a;
    outline:solid 1px #89552a;
    background:url(images/bg.png);
}

#container ul[editable] li {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-color: #0d0d0d;
    color:#fff;
}
```

I guess you already knew this though. :)

Comment: Yes, `!important` plays no role in specificity and as such, can only be applied to individual declarations and not selectors.

Comment: Yeah I knew this. But you gave me an idea! 

"body ul[editable] li {" should work great. Thanks!

@BoltClock, is there an alternative to !important or making the selector more specific?

Comment: Great, but I' not sure if the body tag will be specific enough (ids add a higher value in the specificity sum than tags). But you'll figure it out, I'm sure.